# Loading static files in node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a node application in which I am initializing
 var app = express()
 I am initializing some routes by passing this(app) to a function in one of node_modules of my application. addRoutes(app) is a function where I am defining my static folders

```
addRoutes = function (app) {
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname ));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.html')

})
}
```

this addRoutes is present in one of node_modules

And my "_dirname" is a typical angular app in which there is a assets folder
and all static files are present there but when I go to 
localhost:3000 none of my static files gets loaded. What am I doing wrong here

Comment: did you try specifying a mount path `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/static_folder'));`

Comment: yes I tried, but it didn''t work

Comment: just check your browser console for network request, see what request url for static resources are like.